# JavaScript Window.Open location feature not working

Tags: javascript

In my `window.open` I've set the `location` to `no`.  As I understand it, this should open a popup window with no address bar.  However, when the popup window appears it has an address bar in all browsers except for Safari.  How can I open a new window without an address bar?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var win = window.open("<%= Uri %>", "_blank", "directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,status=no");
    if (win != undefined) {
        window.location.href = '<%= this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri %>';
    }
});
```

Comment: Many browsers don't let you disable some features due to security reasons

Comment: newer browsers don't let you do evil things like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can never *guarantee* that the user won't see window features you ask to be hidden, because some browsers (Firefox, I know, and maybe others) allow the browser user to control what features can be disabled. On top of that, some plugins add toolbars and don't pay any attention to those parameters to `window.open`.

That said, that parameter *usually* works, as I've successfully used it, and it works in cooperating browsers (including all versions of IE I've tried).

*edit* — I just tried a quick test and it seems to work just fine in Chrome and IE.  Now, Chrome shows a little indicator area at the window top that shows the URL, but it's not really the complete "location" bar.