# How to disable location bar and scroll bars of pop window in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popupwindow

For the following code width and height are working in Chrome but location and scrollbar are not working. Please guide.

```html
<script language="JavaScript"> 
  function newwindow() { 
    window.open('http://localhost/a.php', 'jav',
        'width=300,height=200,resizable=yes,location=no,scrollbars=no'); 
  } 
</script>

<a href="javascript:newwindow()">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: I think location=no will not work as an antiphishing measure.

Comment: @Eineki yeah but i was just putting to make the application neat for the user , and its working in IE but in chrome its not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Window.Open location feature not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570503/javascript-window-open-location-feature-not-working)

Answer (score 18):

Chrome will not allow you to do this for security reasons.  Hiding the address bar makes it easier to pretend you're [somebank.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) when really you're [somenigerianguy.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigerian_scam).

As for the scrollbar, you can use css on `a.php` to hide the scrollbars by setting `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: the answer is pretty good but wht abt this somenigerianguy.com

Comment: Did you means the WASP average Wall Street financial advisor?

Comment: No, that guy has figured out how to steal your money without faking his URL.

Comment: Funny thing is, there's a [property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), `location=yes|no|1|0 Whether or not to display the address field. Default is yes`, that you can set in the third argument for `window.open()`, but it doesn't work as advertised, so wtf.

Comment: @Claudiu I didn't know that back when I wrote that comment. I had only discovered w3fools.com about a month later. Good thing I never used W3schools, anyway. I always thought it to be inferior MDN.

Comment: @B1KMusic: yeah i only discovered w3fools a few days ago, but I never really liked w3schools anyways. i actually didn't discover mdn until recently, am using that now - much better!

Answer (score 2):

To hide the scrollbar: try setting "overflow: hidden;" in the css

You can't open a  popup without location bar like in IE, to workaround this you could use an iframe or some third party jQuery plugin